# Why is a TFS hosting cost so much?

Tags: tfs, hosting

Currently I'm decide move my projects from SVN to TFS, and first idea was buy TFS hosting. But when I was review many hosting providers I was shocked their prices politic. Hosting TFS price begin with 20$ per user/month! I was found price of TFS 2010 and on Microsoft Store it's price 499$. VDS hosting can get with price about 10$ per month. My calculation show what VDS+Buy TFS 2010 will be less then get TFS hosting (I'm working with 5 developers now). 
So my question: Am I right? Or I was missed something and best way get TFS Hosting?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, just curios on the reasons for the switch from SVN to TFS

Comment: I need not only source version control, but and issue tracking system, and I think TFS is very nice.

Comment: Although this is a good question, I'm not sure it's a good question for SO. I'm not exactly sure where it would belong, however...

Answer (score 4):

If you fire one of your developers so there are only five of you in total then you could consider the free TFS Express:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=29919

Answer (score 2):

The official list of [Team Foundation Server 2010 hosting providers is here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/team-foundation-server/overview).

You're right that the minimum cost is around $15-$20/user/month. The reason for this is that the hosting providers **have** to use [SPLA licensing](http://www.microsoft.com/hosting/en/us/licensing/splabenefits.aspx) from Microsoft. In addition to a Windows SAL (subscriber access license), they also need to charge for the TFS SAL. I don't know the exact pricing, but I'm guessing that it comes pretty close to $15-20/user/month.

Another part of this is that TFS 2010 is not quite a full multi-tenant application. Although you can add multiple collections (SQL databases) to a single TFS installation, every collection consumes some shared resources (procedure cache, application tier memory, etc). This increases the infrastructure costs for a hosting provider.

There is good news though. Microsoft are working to offer TFS hosting themselves built on the Windows Azure platform. In doing so, they are optimizing the product to work with large numbers of different tenants/customers. No pricing has been announced as yet, but there is a free preview available at http://tfspreview.com/. You can read more about it on [Brian Harry's blog here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2011/05/18/update-on-tfs-on-azure.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out [the hosted preview](http://tfspreview.com)? You can use it now free of charge. In the future we will charge you for this hosted offering. Unfortunately, we don't know yet what the prices will be.

Comment: It's 2013. Any information on the planned pricing?

Comment: See http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/pricing/information/

Comment: There is no pricing information on that page. Unless you mean "free" and "MSDN subscription".

Comment: There is no announcement on pricing yet. Stay tuned though.

Comment: There is still no information on pricing. It's almost November.